# Converting a list of ints into something compatible with locations in another list While creating a Hangman game

Tags: python

I've been working on hangman project recently, I have used enumerate to get the locations of a letter that's been guessed so i can put it into a list, but when i try and put it into "guess" list, it comes up with:
Edit: I do understand that you cannot simply change an entire list into a series of ints by doing int(list), it's simply a place holder

Here is my code

```
import random
lines = []
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    lines.append(line)
choice = random.choice(lines)
#print("it says", choice)
guessed = False
print("Your word is", len(choice), "letters long!")
answer =         ["_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_"]
wrong = 0
= 1
print(choice)
while not guessed:
guess = input("Guess a letter!")
#location = choice.find(guess)
location = [i for i, a in enumerate(choice) if a == guess]
print(location)
if wrong == 6:
    print("Sorry, you have killed yourself.")
    guessed = True
elif not location:
    wrong += 1
    print("Sorry, that was not part of the word!")
    print("You have", (6 - wrong), "guesses left")
elif right == len(choice):
    answer[int(location)] = guess
    print(answer[0:len(choice)])
    print("Congratulations! You have won!")
    guessed = True
else:
    right += 1
    answer[location] = guess
    print(answer[0:len(choice)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has other issues beyond this but as your question at hand, it is here:

```
elif right == len(choice):
    answer[int(location)] = guess
    print(answer[0:len(choice)])
    print("Congratulations! You have won!")
    guessed = True
else:
    right += 1
    answer[location] = guess
    print(answer[0:len(choice)])
```

Your two statements `answer[int(location)] = guess` and `answer[location] = guess` if you print `location` it is a list, for a 4 letter word example `vash`, `location` is a list of range `[0,3]` you are attempting to pass the entire `list` as an `index` which will not work regardless if you convert it to `int` or not.

Please try this modification, this is not a full solution, I do not want to take away from your journey on this project but this will get your moving:

```
import random
lines = ['hey', 'this', 'that']
choice = random.choice(lines)
#print("it says", choice)
guessed = False
print("Your word is", len(choice), "letters long!")
answer =         ["_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_"]
wrong = 0
right = 0
print(choice)
while not guessed:
    guess = input("Guess a letter!")
    #location = choice.find(guess)
    if wrong == 6:
        print("Sorry, you have killed yourself.")
        guessed = True
    elif guess not in choice:
        wrong += 1
        print("Sorry, that was not part of the word!")
        print("You have", (6 - wrong), "guesses left")
    elif right == len(choice):
        print(answer)
        print("Congratulations! You have won!")
        guessed = True
    else:
        right += 1
        answer[choice.index(guess)] = guess
        print(answer[0:len(choice)])
```

Comment: You're right about the other issues, this problem is my priority, and i can clean up the rest later, as I don't see how making `answer[int(location)]` helps the issue as it is still passing a list into the `answer[]`

Comment: `Your word is 9 letters long!
REMURMURS
Guess a letter!R
[0, 4, 7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hirsc/PycharmProjects/Practice/Hangman.py", line 35, in <module>
    answer[int(location)] = guess
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list' ` is what comes up for me.

Comment: @Hirschy running for me

Comment: @Hirschy okay now I see there was indentation issue in your question posted looking into it now

Comment: I tried copying your edit into a new project and it came up with `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'` as an error. on line 34

Comment: updated answer to explain what is happening @Hirschy

Comment: Thanks, I understand that, I was hoping there was a way to get the contents to be passed as ints to that location in my code.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually almost exactly what I had before i switched over to attempting something with enumerate. Since, in the game of hangman, if there are multiple of a letter you get all instances of that letter to be filled in. If i can brainstorm anything else out, I'll let you know. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: @Hirschy no problem!  Appreciate if you accepted answer, cheers :)